# jpa: how to check if an entity is persisted?

Tags: jpa

JPA entity: how to check if an entity has been persisted?

1. check id:

   entity id may be set by user before persisting it. So it is not reliable.
2. check version:

   version is not required for an entity.
3. em.contains(entity)

   if the entity is detached, it will return false.

Comment: em.find ? (after clearing L1/L2 caches)

Comment: "entity id may be set by user before persisting it.". Never provide users users with a means to set or alter ids.

Comment: The entity will be persisted when the trasaction is commited ..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a logger inside listener method annotated with `@PostPersist` .. check [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html) for more info

Answer (score -2):

JPA's `save` method returns the persisted entity.

You can simply `null` check to find if a given entity is persisted or not like so.

```
User user = userRepository.save(new User(FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME));
if(user != null) {
    //User entity is successfully persisted.
}
```

From the [`docs`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-)

> `<S extends T> S save(S entity)`
>
> Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations
> as the save operation might have changed the entity instance
> completely.
>
> Parameters: entity - must not be null.
>
> Returns: the saved entity **will never be null.**

Comment: we can check from save() method. But in general given an entity, how to check if it has been persisted without loading it again?